# How to specify azure storage connection string in node js?

Tags: azure, storage, node.js

I'm trying to use azure storage for storing the assets in node js application. I followed the official documentation. But the connection string specification is not working. So i'm getting error.

> throw new SyntaxError(SR.INVALID_CONNECTION_STRING); ^
>
> SyntaxError: Connection strings must be of the form "key1=value1;key2=value2".
>
> at Object.exports.parseAndValidateKeys (/home/sakthips/Downloads/Projects/node/storage-blobs-node-quickstart/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/servicesettings.js:83:15)

In the .env file, i specified like this

```
AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING='DefaultEndpointsProtocol=****..'
```

but it's not working. Can anyone explain why it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .env must be read before azure store gets initialized. Use

```
require('dotenv').load();
```

And do not call

```
const storage = require('azure-storage')
```

until just before it is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

The `dotenv` load sequence seems not matter, I require `dotenv` after `azure-storage` 
 is loaded and still can verified the queue is created.

My code as follows:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');

require("dotenv").config();

var queueSvc = azure.createQueueService();

queueSvc.createQueueIfNotExists('myqueue', function(error, results, response){
  if(!error){
    // Queue created or exists
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(results);
});
```

My Connection String for reference:
`AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;`